# Windows Server 2012 R2でPIAを使用するには？

Tags: windows-server

お世話になっております。

今回、Windows Server 2012 R2にOffice 2007をインストールし、PIA for office2007をインストールしようとしたら、出来ませんでした。

PIA for office2007はWindows Server 2012をサポートしていないのかもしれません。

Windows Server 2012 R2で使用するには、どのバージョンのOffice、どのバージョンのPIAを用いればよいのでしょうか？

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: PIAとは「Office プライマリ相互運用機能アセンブリ (Primary Interop Assembly)」のことでしょうか？

Comment: はい、仰った通りです。

Comment: マルチポスト: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516977/install-pia-for-windows-server-2012-r2

Answer (score 0):

使用する.NET Frameworkのバージョンは3.5 / 4系のどちらでしょうか？

[エンド ユーザーのコンピューターで Office PIA が必要な場合について](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/3295w01c.aspx#Office-PIA)には

> 既定では、プロジェクトの各 Office PIA 参照の **[相互運用型の埋め込み]** プロパティが **[True]** (これが既定値です) に設定されているときは、エンド ユーザーのコンピューターに Office プライマリ相互運用機能アセンブリ (PIA: Primary Interop Assembly) がインストールされている必要はありません。

とありますように、インストールする必要がありません。ただし、この機能を使用するにはVisual Studio 2010以降および.NET Framework 4以降を使用する必要があります。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-to-install-Primary-Interop-Assemblies-PIA-and-Office-Visual-Studio-Runtime-manually&language=en_US&type=1　に書いてあるように、恐らく必要がないのはOffice 2007 2010 より新しいOfficeだと思います。こちら実際に試したところ、どうしてもOffice 2007はPIAのインストールが必要になります。。